# How to pass array of element as argument in includes keyword in reactjs or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, filter, react-redux

I have written code which uses the `includes` keyword for filtering

```
Const filteredData=candidate 

Data.filter(item=>checkboxData.includes(item.skill.map(I=>{return i})))
CheckboxData=[html,css..]

CandidateData=[{name:Alan,skill:[html,css]}]
```

Comment: Jibin, you've asked another question that is difficult to understand. Please read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as I suggested last time making sure the code in your question is relevant and added as a [mcve], and your question is formatted properly and easy to read.

Comment: You are probably looking for [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) I don't really understand your question and I don't think I'm the only one. Could you post code as code and some example data and outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    const languages=['HTML','CSS','JavaScript','Python','Ruby']
    const data=[
        {name:'Alan',skill:['HTML','CSS']},
        {name:'Dan',skill:['Java']},
        {name:'Sara',skill:['C++']},
        {name:'Ram',skill:['Ruby','JavaScript']}
      ]

    const filteredData=data.filter((item)=>
        item.skill.filter(language=>
            languages.includes(language)).length>0 && item)
```

Comment: Its working but now I need to filter only the data when all the elements in languages is there in the skill any method bro for array matching

Comment: const filterData=data.filter((item)=>
      languages.every(language=>
        item.skill.includes(language)) && item 
    )